# implementing INotifyPropertyChanged

Tags: c#, wpf, inotifypropertychanged, wpftoolkit, wizard

I am trying to make a wizard in wpf using the wpf toolkit extended wizard control.

I need to prevent the user from proceeding to the next page unless certain conditions are met.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26965271/369) to another question suggested binding the `CanSelectNextPage` property to a boolean property in the code behind the current page.

I am having trouble implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged`. In the answer linked above, his `MainWindow` class extends `INotifyPropertyChanged`.  How is that possible? Wouldn't the `MainWindow` class have to extend the Window class?

Also, what assembly is `INotifyPropertyChanged` located in?  [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) says it is in `System.ObjectModel.dll` which I don't seem to have...

Comment: By the way, a new question should be a question, not a comment. You were correct to post this as a question. Looks like the commenting restriction actually worked as intended for once :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

His MainWindow class *implements* INotifyPropertyChanged, which is found in System.ComponentModel.

This MSDN article should explain how to use it: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.100).aspx

INotifyPropertyChanged will notify clients, such as your UI, when a given property changes. You could bind the visibility of your 'next' button to a boolean property of your class, and set the boolean property to true once all of your other properties are set.

EDIT: I should add that in order to bind a boolean value to the visibility of a button, you'll need to use an IValueConverter.

Answer (score 0):

First off, `INotifyPropertyChanged` is an interface, not a class. So while a class can inherit from a single class only (here the `Window` class), it can implement multiple interfaces.

The interface itself is located in the `System.dll` assembly in the `System.ComponentModel` namespace.